# Django URL Patterns

Tags: python, django, url, url-pattern

I've created a very simple blog, but have been running into a couple URL issues. For my tag & specific post views I run into the following issues.

**Specific Post View Example**
These two sites render the same, and would like the second one to render a 404. 
website.com/post/1/hello-world 
 website.com/post/1/hello-world/non-sense (should render 404)

**Tag View**
website.com/tag/python: this will render all posts tagged python, great. However...
website.com/tag/python/party: this will render all posts tagged "python/party" instead of rendering a 404.

Here is my URL patterns setup so you can take a look.

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<post_title>)', DetailView.as_view(
                        model = post,
                        template_name = "post.html")),
url(r'^post/$', ListView.as_view(
                        queryset = post.objects.all().order_by("-date"),
                        template_name = "archives.html")),
url(r'^archives/$', ListView.as_view(
                        queryset = post.objects.all().order_by("-date"),
                        template_name = "archives.html")),
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[\w|\W]+)', 'tags'),
```

**Updated**
Solution for tag:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[\w]+)\W*/$', 'tags'),
```

Solution for post:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<post_url>[\w-]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
                        model = post,
                        template_name = "post.html")),
```

**Thank you Huckleberry Finn and krakax for all the help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **post** `URLconf` regex

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<post_title>)', DetailView.as_view(
                    model = post,
                    template_name = "post.html")),
```

Should changed to

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<post_title>[-\w]+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
                    model = post,
                    template_name = "post.html")),
```

means `URLconf` is ending with end-slash

Anyway, Try to define you `DetailView` `URLconf` after post `ListView`. In my opinion if you change your list view and detailview to `posts/` and `post/` you problem will be solved. The solution is same for `tags` `URLconf` issue.

Comment: Hey Huck, I've tried this, but I get the 404 error `The current URL, post/1/hello-world/, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: I get the `posts/` `post/`, but adding `/$` as below I get a 404 error not being able to match the URL. `url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<post_title>)/$', DetailView.as_view(
                    model = post,
                    template_name = "post.html")),`

Comment: @alxmrph you have to define allowed characters for you <post_title> arg, see the updated answer.

Comment: Is there a place where I can view a list of possible arguments? My post titles are slugs, so they all have `-` hyphens which could be my issue of why it's not matching the URL to a URL pattern. Any idea? Thanks so much for the help Huck. I appreciate it!

Comment: @alxmrph if they are slug then `<post_title>[-\w]` is the solution.

Comment: Thanks, Huck! I've got it all in working order now. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex

```
r'^tag/(?P<tag>[\w|\W]+)'
```

means that group tag will contain all caracters after 'tag/'. [\w|\W] means 'all alphanumerics' or 'all but alphanumerics'. This is equivalent to 'all caracters'.

It should be changed to

```
r'^tag/(?P<tag>[\w]+)\W*'
```

This will stop your group at first non alphanumeric

Comment: Hey @Krakax this works great in preventing it from altering the tag query upon receiving a non-alphanumeric character, but website.com/tag/python/non-sense still renders website.com/python instead of a 404. Any ideas? Thanks for all your help I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: found the solution for tag, thanks! still working on the post detail view if you have any advice.

Comment: Read my second answer to add the optional nature of your '/' if you want. For POST, do the same, but use (?P<tag>[\w-]+) to add '-' in your match.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, right now I see 2 ways.

First, change to:

```
r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)(?P<end>\W.*)'
```

(BTW, [] is not necessary in your case) This way, you get the group called 'end' as a parameter of your tag controller and you can test it and redirect to your 404 custom page or generate a 404 classic error.

Second possibility is:
Add another url hook and controller:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)\W*', 'tags404'),

url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)$', 'tags'),
```

This way, you forbid any url that contains others caracters than alphanumerics after the 'tag/'.

If you want to allow just one optional '/' at the end, you can write in place of your new hook:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>\w+)/?$', 'tags'),
```

Comment: Thanks @krakax! This is the solution that I ended up going with for tag: `url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[\w]+)\W*/$', 'tags'),`